# How to delete n elements from an array of two nested lists without losing the array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I am working with a nested structure like this:

```
l=[

[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'bannana', 'grapes']],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'apricot', avocado]],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'tomato']],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon','pear','strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'apricot', 2]]

 ]
```

How can I preserve an arbitrary number of elements from each element (sublist) of two nested lists? For example, say I want to preserve at least 5 elements. The expected output should be:

```
 ]

    [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon']],
    [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon']],
    [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon']],
    [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon']]

 ]
```

Or 9:

```
[

[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'bannana', 'grapes']],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'strawberry']],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'strawberry']],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon','pear','strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry']]

]
```

Or 11:

```
[

[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'bannana', 'grapes']],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'apricot', avocado]],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'tomato']],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon','pear','strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry']]

]
```

Alternatively, consider this list:

```
l2 = [

[['apple'], ['watermelon']],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'apricot', avocado]],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'tomato']],
[['apple', 'tomato'], ['watermelon','pear','strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'apricot', 2]]

]
```

If I want 4, the output should look like this:

```
[

[['apple'], ['watermelon']],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'],[]],
[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'],[]],
[['apple', 'tomato'], ['watermelon','pear']]

]
```

I could iterate and join over each sublist. However, If I do that I might break the inner lists inside the list. Any idea of how to remove a number elements without losing the `[[],[]]` structure efficiently?

Comment: What should happen if the number were 4 or less?

Comment: You just take for for that [[],[]] pair @MyNameIsCaleb

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb I added an example

Comment: do you need to change the input list in-place or produce a new list?

Comment: Which option is more convinient for large lists? @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @anon, the difference is obvious: in one case you have the same data structure, in other - you have 2 data structures in memory

Comment: I would prefer to have one structure in memory @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `for` loop:

```
res = []
n = 4
for li, lj in l2:
    res.append([li[:n], lj[:max(0,n-len(li))]])
res
```

Output:

```
[[['apple'], ['watermelon']],
 [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], []],
 [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], []],
 [['apple', 'tomato'], ['watermelon', 'pear']]]
```

With `l` and `n=5`:

```
res = []
n = 5
for li, lj in l:
    res.append([li[:n], lj[:max(0,n-len(li))]])
res
```

Output:

```
[[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon']],
 [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon']],
 [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon']],
 [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon']]]
```

Comment: Will OP have inner lists more than 2 elements?

Comment: @ggorlen Possibly. But OP also stated _each element (sublist) of two nested lists_ so I took a shoot ;). In case of 2 **or more**, a bit more work will be necessary, but let's wait for OP to confirm.

Comment: Oh yeah, good reading. This does it, then.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys @Chris and ggorlen

Answer (score 2):

To *cut* the input list in-place (using Python's `list.clear()` feature):

```
import pprint

def cut_list(lst, n):
    for i, (l1, l2) in enumerate(lst):
        if len(l1 + l2) > n:  # check if there are items to cut
            if len(l1) >= n:  # if the 1st sublist covers the limit
                lst[i][0] = l1[:n]
                lst[i][1].clear()   # clear the 2nd sublist in-place
            else:             # cut the 2nd sublist leaving the 1st one intact
                lst[i][1] = l2[:n - len(l1)]


lst = [
    [['apple'], ['watermelon']],
    [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'],
     ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'apricot', 'avocado']],
    [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'],
     ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'tomato']],
    [['apple', 'tomato'],
     ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry',
      'apricot', 2]]
]

cut_list(lst, 4)
pprint.pprint(lst)
```

The output:

```
[[['apple'], ['watermelon']],
 [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], []],
 [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], []],
 [['apple', 'tomato'], ['watermelon', 'pear']]]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

```
for arr_2d in l:
    assert len (arr_2d) == 2
    fir_arr = arr_2d[0]
    sec_arr = arr_2d[1]
    arr_2d[1] = sec_arr[0:n-len(fir_arr)]
```

It works. I have tested.

```
for arr_2d in l: # iterate each 2D array inside l
    assert len (arr_2d) == 2 # make sure the current 2D array has 2 elements
    fir_arr = arr_2d[0] # assign variable
    sec_arr = arr_2d[1] # to each of this 2d array
    arr_2d[1] = sec_arr[0:n-len(fir_arr)] # pythonic way to cut the second element based on the number of items in the first
```

Output:

l

```
Out[50]: 
[[['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon']],
 [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon']],
 [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon']],
 [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear', 'watermelon'], ['watermelon']]]
```

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, I was waiting for your edit!

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
>>> def shrink( b, keep ) :
...     result = []
...     for bb in b :
...         if keep < 1 : break
...         result.append( bb[:keep] )
...         keep -= len(bb)
...     return result
... 
>>> [shrink( b, 6 ) for b in a]
print json.dumps( [shrink( b, 6 ) for b in a], indent=4)
[[
    [
        "apple", 
        "bannana", 
        "pear", 
        "watermelon"
    ], 
    [
        "watermelon", 
        "pear"
    ]
], 
[
    [
        "apple", 
        "bannana", 
        "pear", 
        "watermelon"
    ], 
    [
        "watermelon", 
        "pear"
    ]
], 
[
    [
        "apple", 
        "bannana", 
        "pear", 
        "watermelon"
    ], 
    [
        "watermelon", 
        "pear"
    ]
], 
[
    [
        "apple", 
        "bannana", 
        "pear", 
        "watermelon"
    ], 
    [
        "watermelon", 
        "pear"
    ]
]
]
>>>
```

Comment: Its wrong, because overall you should sum from the two lists the given number

Comment: For example, when you try with `l2` you get this:`[[['apple'], ['watermelon']],
 [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry']],
 [['apple', 'bannana', 'pear'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry']],
 [['apple', 'tomato'], ['watermelon', 'pear', 'strawberry']]]` which is wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: sorry, forgot `keep -= len(bb)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that works for arbitrarily-sized inner lists:

```
def truncate_inner(it, keep):
    for x in it:
        yield x[:max(0, keep)]
        keep -= len(x)
```

Usage for a 3d list such as `l2`:

```
for row in [list(truncate_inner(x, 3)) for x in l2]:
    print(row)
```